try upgrade to 24.04.1 on usb3 copy of my system?
This weekend I tried to upgrace my NUC (intel i5) system with Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS (KDE desktop) to 24.04.1 LTS. It failed. First time with an empty (!) error message but later I found 107 messages "Holding Back xxx rather then changing yyy" in the apt.log file. After removing 2 not-standard packages+repositories and apt autoremove, the rerun of the upgrade still gave 52 of these errors. After some internet searching I managed to restore the apt configuration and got back to a working 22.04 system.
Now I like to make a bootable copy of my 256GB system disk on a 250GB USB3 SSD to further test and fix all problems with this upgrade.
How do I do that, while still keeping my original system unchanged and bootable?
Or might this be faster: do a fresh 24.04 install, install programs and modules that I need, and restore my own data?

Reinstall is surely faster, but you won't learn what past mistakes to avoid repeating. Testing and learning is slower, but offers advantages for some users.

I like to test these out on virtual machines. You can clone your system to a VM using Clonezilla. You could probably clone it to a USB but I haven't done that. Doing it my way is an argument for having a separate /home partition, so you can quickly clone just / without having to copy all the /home data.

Thanks all,I will go for the full install. Not that I've made mistakes, but to get rid of old libraries, programs and tools that I needed at some time in the past but not anymore, or need upgrades too.

... I made a full image copy of the OS disk using Clonezilla, just in caseOn my ubuntu desktop and laptop - with a SSD for the OS and a large HD -, I use BackInTime for daily backups of my Home dir (on the SSD) to the HD. Restoring that is also easy.
